# OpenSSL not getting linked with homebrew on El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: macos, homebrew, openssl

I am trying to code in C on OS X (El Capitan) and need to use OpenSSL. OS ships with version `0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`.

I used homebrew to upgrade and install openssl (got version 1.0.2h) but am unable to link it correctly to use it. This is what is did:

```
brew update

brew install openssl

brew link --force openssl
```

which gave me error saying

`Warning: Refusing to link: openssl`.

My path references `/usr/local/bin` as the first one.

Ran this command: 
`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j/include/openssl /usr/local/include/openssl`

(found this solution here: [Openssl with El Capitan](https://medium.com/@zlwaterfield/openssl-with-el-capitan-456bf68bf43a#.f9tkjeo7w) among other places)

got no error output, so I assumed this worked. But..

`which openssl` gives me this output: `/usr/local/bin/openssl`

`openssl version` gives me this output: `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`

All I'm trying to do is run some CLI commands/ write some C code edited in plain `vi` editor, compiled using `gcc`. I am including openssl in header files using

```
 #include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/ripemd.h>
```

Also, the command I am running on CLI which led me to this path was this (if that helps):

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ec-priv.pem ex-message.txt >ex-signature.der.
```

Gives me an error:

```
EVP_SignFinal:wrong public key type.
```

Googling led me to understand it's cause of an old OpenSSL version which I need to update.

Any ideas on how to proceed here?

Comment: Have you entered a new shell after lionking the file but before running whgich? For the C compile we need to see the C compiler and linker command lines

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Opening a new shell and running `openssl version` showed me the correct version. SO it got linked properly and i was just not seeing the correct version as i was running it all in old shell. I am putting this here as answer as i am not allowed to comment. Couldn't find any other way to respond to you. If you put this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure you open a new shell after performing the link. 
(I updated my medium article you linked for future reference: [Openssl with El Capitan](https://medium.com/@zlwaterfield/openssl-with-el-capitan-456bf68bf43a)).

Comment: This alters the executabe but doe not chnage the include or link paths

Answer (score 1):

From [Brew refusing to link openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295) on Stack Overflow and [Issue 3964, .Net GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3964#issuecomment-236493536) (I think it was first reported with .Net):

> I looked into the other option that was suggested for setting the rpath on the library. I think the following is a better solution that
>   will only effect this specific library.
>
> `sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib`
>
> and/or if you have NETCore 1.0.1 installed perform the same command for 1.0.1 as well:
>
> `sudo install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.1`/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.dylib
>
> In effect, rather than telling the operating system to always use the homebrew version of SSL and potentially causing something to
>   break, we're telling dotnet how to find the correct library.

---

> `which openssl` gives me this output: `/usr/local/bin/openssl`
>
> `openssl version` gives me this output: `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`

Add an rpath to the `openssl` executable. OpenSSL's build system does not supply an rpath. At runtime, your new executable links to the old libraries.