# Installing macOS 10.12.4 beta 2 breaks OpenSSH installed via homebrew

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, ssh, beta-seed-program

- ssh: OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.4.5 (installed via homebrew)
- System Version: macOS 10.12.4 (16E154a)

### Error:

```
me@mymac:~$ ssh foo@bar.local
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _arc4random_buf
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ssh
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/libressl/lib/libcrypto.38.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _arc4random_buf
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ssh
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/libressl/lib/libcrypto.38.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

Any advice how to solve this problem? This also breaks my git pushes (using ssh, obviously)

Comment: Well that looks like a bug in OpenSSL It needs to be linked against the correct library

Comment: related question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244058/homebrew-trouble-upgrading-openssl/265024#265024

Answer (score 4):

`brew reinstall openssh`

Solved the issue completely