# ssh command crashes after key exchange

Tags: terminal, macos, ssh, dynamic-library

Had this strange issue crop up today that I haven't experienced before. I execute `ssh <remote ip>` and ssh crashes with the following exception:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _timingsafe_bcmp
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ssh
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _timingsafe_bcmp
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ssh
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

I have run the command with the verbose flag and can see this is happening directly after the key exchange between the local machine and remote host.

**Things I have tried:**

- Restarting terminal
- Restarting machine
- Removing all ssh programs in /usr/bin and replacing them with those of a colleagues mac
- Booting to recovery mode and replacing libSystem.B.dylib with the one that ships with macOS
- Installing openssh with homebrew
- Removing openssh
- Adding a PATH to /usr/bin

Note the same error appears on other commands such as `scp`.

Comment: Does http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272927/installing-macos-10-12-4-beta-2-breaks-openssh-installed-via-homebrew help?

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're (probably) using homebrew's `ssh`, I found [this reported bug in the openssh formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/716), which apparently can be fixed by upgrading macOS to 10.12.3:

> Right, that symbol wasn't in 10.12.0, […]
>   You can fix it by building from source or by upgrading to 10.12.3.